# ARRAYFORMULA MMULT TRANSPOSE giving the wrong calculation result

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, array-formulas, sumifs

I have the following formula and I can't seem to find out what's wrong as it's producing wrong result.

```
=IFERROR(ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(IFERROR($H$2:$O*1/ISNUMBER($H$2:$O*1),0), TRANSPOSE(IFERROR(($H$2:$O$2 ^ 0)/ISNUMBER($H$2:$O$2 ^ 0),0))) * VLOOKUP($G$2:$G,LookupSheet!$A$2:$B$6,2,FALSE)))
```

Sample Google Sheet data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YNv2Et8l1SXh_KAQB2TDz4iaIieDqhkzVmYT0oePtb4/edit?usp=sharing

In the sample, `ARRAYFORMULA SUMIF` gives the correct result but `ARRAYFORMULA MMULT TRANSPOSE` doesn't. I can't use `ARRAYFORMULA SUMIF` due to poor performance in a 30,000 rows (growing) x 22 columns spreadsheet and it's affecting all my other spreadsheets which utilise the data using `IMPORTRANGE`.

Appreciate if someone can look into this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what should your formula do?

Comment: @player0 whenever there's new data entry, for each row, sum up all the % from column H to O (shall ignore the text "N/A"), then lookup and multiply with the Capacity based on Type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MMULT(IFERROR(INDIRECT("H2:O"&MAX((G2:G<>"")*(ROW(G2:G))))*1, 0), 
 TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(H:O))^0)*
 VLOOKUP(INDIRECT("G2:G"&MAX((G2:G<>"")*(ROW(G2:G)))), LookupSheet!A2:B, 2, 0))
```

[image]

Comment: it works! thank you so much! sorry if this is a silly question, but what went wrong with my formula? Regardless, I'll learn from your formula. :-)

Comment: @Shyuan this part failed you - https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUbHY.png - it should look like in S column but you got there zeros which mess up the final output